# Hot to get the value from the form to the php as it was incremented and decremented

Tags: php, html

I wanted to get the incremented and decremented number and print it out to the php.
This is my code:

```
       <p>Quantity:</p>
       <ul>
       <li><button id = "decrement" onclick="decrement()"><i class = "fa fa-minus"></i>
         </button></li>

       <li>

       <form action="" method ="get">
            <input id="quantity" type="number" name="quant" value="0" min="0">
        </form>

       </li>
       <li><button id = "increment" onclick="increment()"><i class = "fa fa-plus"></i></button></li>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
            function increment(){
                document.getElementById('quantity').stepUp();
            }

            function decrement(){
                document.getElementById('quantity').stepDown();

            }
        </script>
        <p>
        <?php
        $qty = $_GET['quant'];
        echo $qty;
        ?></p>
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You are using $_GET which works by fetching from Url. Do you wish to echo the value dynamically, or during a final submission using "Submit" kind of button? PHP is not meant to handle these dynamic DOM changes.

Comment: @Deepak I should get the value of the quantity and pass it to the next page which you can say the " Add to cart" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something I put together. It's a very minimal example, but should help you get started. Added comments so it should help you understand how the code is working.

```html
<?php
  // gets the value submitted by the form
  $number = isset($_POST['txtNumber']) ? $_POST['txtNumber'] : 0;
?>
<!-- action is an empty string ("") because the PHP is on the same page as this HTML -->
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="number" id="txtNumber" name="txtNumber" min="0" value="<?php echo $number; ?>">
  <button id="btnIncrease">+</button>
  <button id="btnDecrease">-</button>
</form>

<?php
  echo 'The number is currently ' . $number;
?>

<script>
// when the + button is clicked on
document.querySelector('#btnIncrease').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // gets the number from the input and adds one to it
  var number = Number(document.querySelector('#txtNumber').value) + 1;
  // update the input with the updated number
  document.querySelector('#txtNumber').value = number;
  // submits the HTML form, PHP handles the rest
  document.querySelector('form').submit();
});
// when the - button is clicked on
document.querySelector('#btnDecrease').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // gets the number from the input and removes one from it
  var number = Number(document.querySelector('#txtNumber').value) - 1;
  // update the input with the updated number
  document.querySelector('#txtNumber').value = number;
  // submits the HTML form, PHP handles the rest
  document.querySelector('form').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: It helped but I should get the value of the quantity and pass it to the next page which you can say the " Add to cart" page. Should I put in the action = "AddtoCart", to pass it in there?

Comment: You need another php page for that. addtocart.php for example, and yes, you can do `action="addtocart.php"` to send the quantity to that PHP script.